# Why the C# System.IO.Abstractions library is writing to disc?

Tags: c#, filesystems

According to the documentation [System.IO.Abstractions](https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions) writes only to memory, not to disc, then why this code is writing to disc? I'm very confused.

```
using System.IO.Abstractions;

public class Settings 
{
  readonly IFileSystem fileSystem;

  public Settings(IFileSystem fileSystem)
  {
    this.fileSystem = fileSystem;
  }

  public Update()
  {
    this.fileSystem.File.WriteAllText(Path, Text);  // writing to disc ???
  }
}
```

Comment: What concrete type does `fileSystem` have? If it's `new FileSystem()`, the docs say "default implementation which calls System.IO". If it's a `MockFileSystem`, yes it should be in-memory only

Comment: There's not a single mention anywhere that it only works in memory, this question doesn't make sense. Even the main page has the following: `fileSystem: new FileSystem() //use default implementation which calls System.IO`

Comment: `FileSystem` enables you to mock `System.IO`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the right concrete type when calling the `Settings` constructor. If the `fileSystem` writes to disk, you are using:

```
System.IO.Abstractions:FileSystem
```

Instead use:

```
System.IO.Abstractions.TestingHelpers:MockFileSystem
```

Comment: Ok, I see, but what is the purpose of having 2 contructors and explicity instancing "new FileSystem()"? For example this post http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Unit-Testing-C-File-Access-Code-with-SystemIOAbstractions says: "If the parameterless constructor is used (e.g. in production) an instance of FileSystem will be used, however at test time, a mock IFileSystem can be supplied". So I thought that one constructor is used for Production and the other one for testing, and that's why I got confused since in my code I have only 1 constructor. BTW, do we really need 2 constructors?